# user\AppData\Local\SysHashTable folder (Win10)

Tags: windows-10

What is this folder for and can it be deleted? There are many subfolders (cca 100k) in this folder and they seem to be all empty.

I am tempted to delete the whole thing, because it slows down search in my users folder, but am not sure whether it is safe.

Comment: That folder doesn't exist for me. Probably that folder is created by a third-party program.

Comment: This folder name is associated with Malware https://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2017-041016-2115-99&tabid=2 Not saying it is; you could have something legit creating the same thing.

Comment: Many thanks, will explore the third party/malware program.